# How to add QLabel to QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsItem` that has text on it.  I want this text to be editable, so that if the user double-clicks it, it will enter an edit mode.  It seems like the easiest way to do this would be to change the text into a `QLineEdit` and let the user click away the focus or press enter when they're done.

How can I add a `QLineEdit` to a `QGraphicsItem`?  I have subclassed the `QGraphicsItem` so I have access to its internals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add any `QWidget` based object to a `QGraphicsScene`, a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` is required.

When you call the function `addWidget` on `QGraphicsScene`, it embeds the widget in a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` and returns that `QGraphicsProxyWidget` back to the caller.

The `QGraphicsProxyWidget` forwards events to its widget and handles conversion between the different coordinate systems.

Now that you're looking at using a `QLineEdit` in the `QGraphicsScene`, you need to decide if you want to add it directly:

```
QGraphicsScene* pScene = new QGraphicsScene;
QLineEdit* pLineEdit = new QLineEdit("Some Text");

// add the widget - internally, the QGraphicsProxyWidget is created and returned
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pProxyWidget = pScene->AddWidget(pLineEdit);
```

Or just add it to your current `QGraphicsItem`. 
Here, you can either add it as a child of the `QGraphicsItem`:

```
MyQGraphicsItem* pMyItem = new MyQGraphicsItem;
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pMyProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(pMyItem); // the proxy's parent is pMyItem
pMyProxy->setWidget(pLineEdit); // adding the QWidget based object to the proxy
```

Or you could add the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` as a member of your class and call its relevant functions, but adding it as a child is probably much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

```
QGraphicsTextItem::setTextInteractionFlags (Qt::TextInteractionFlags flags)
```

API can be used. But you need to create `QGraphicsTextItem` inside it.

Please check following link for details: [Implementation details](http://www.qtforum.org/article/23314/qt4-qgraphicstextitem-in-a-qgraphicsitem.html)

Comment: @Freedom_Ben QLineEdit is a QWidget, so if you want QLineEdit instead of QGraphicsTextItem . Then better go diffrent approach already answered by "mhcuervo".

Comment: this was actually a good answer since most overlook this functionality, and adding QWidgets and the associated proxy items is a whole other can of worms that you might not want to get into if you are looking for simplicity, not to mention overall performance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a proxy widget by extending `QGraphicsProxyWidget` in the case you need some specific behavior or just use a `QGraphicsProxyWidget`. Take a look at the "Embedded Dialogs" example in your Qt SDK and the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` documentation. It has been there for a long time so it should be for your version. I hope this helps.